# Changing working directory is failing in local package tests (testthat) but not on travis

Tags: r, travis-ci, testthat

I have a function in my R package which needs to compile an external library located in `pkg/extdata`. As it is made to be compiled from a certain directory I go to that dir using `setwd()` and I go back to the previously saved directory after the installation. 
The weirdness is that the tests (using testthat) of this function fail locally but not on the travis ci ubuntu:16.04 container/VM (the same as mine). To find and change dir (in `extdata`) I do the following:

`pkg_source <- system.file('extdata/pkg_lib', "src", package = "pkg")
odir <- getwd()
setwd(pkg_source)`

The output error is:

`` test_it.R:4: failure: Test install_it
`install_it()` threw an error.
Message: cannot change working directory
Class:   simpleError/error/condition ``

My idea is that the folder in which packages are installed have some restriction but it is illogical if you consider that no sudo right is needed and on the server is going towards the end smoothly.

If it helps, my lib path is `.libPaths()
[1] "/home/uuuser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/site-library" "/usr/lib/R/library"`

Comment: There was no real solution to this problem. I used a workaround and changed the software in extdata so to have it installed independently from the file location. Still an alternative solution could be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you shouldn't have to change working directories in a package. Can you avoid the error by just working with the package data loaded or sourced in from the existing file location?

Comment: It is not possible as I am not the administrator of the external library and it does not support another way of installation. I can press the mod, but I wanted to fix this weird and unnecessary error in the meantime they examine my request.